# BIM360 app: Authentication of 3rd party apps added from BIM360 Store

Tags: autodesk-bim360

1. What is the recommended method of obtaining access token by a 3rd party web-app added to BIM360 account from BIM360 Store? Could someone point me to correct documentation?
2. When API access is enabled in BIM360 Docs, it only provides Client ID (not Client Secret). Is the correct understanding?
3. As such, we will have to depend on a "3-legged Token with Implicit Grant”, which can be obtained without Client Secret. What happens if user stays on 3rd party app's page (without returning to BIM360 page)? Does the token expires? If so, how does 3rd party app refreshes the token without Client Secret?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation about the 3-legged workflow on our developer center:

[Get a 3-Legged Token with Authorization Code Grant](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/)

[Get 3-legged Token with Implicit Grant](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token-implicit/)

We also have articles on our Forge blog:

[Landing your Forge OAuth authentication workflow](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/07/landing-your-forge-oauth-authentication-workflow.html)

[3-legged OAuth on desktop apps (C# & WinForm)](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/10/3-legged-oauth-on-desktop-apps-c-winform.html)

And multiple samples on our [github repository](https://github.com/autodesk-forge).

Client Secret should always stay secured on your own server and never be shared with any application.

3-legged token expire after 30 minutes, as mentioned in the [link](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token-implicit/) I pointed out above:

> The main difference here from the authorization code grant type is
>   that the client receives the access token as the result of the
>   authorization request. The refresh token is not issued in this case
>   which requires repeating the authorization process once the access
>   token expires.

Comment: Thank you Philippe! Let me explain my problem in bit more details:

I understand that the token expires after 30 minutes - whichever way we obtain it. So, if I expect user to stay-on on my app for a longer time, I cannot depend on Implicit Grant, because my app will have no way to refresh the token. Correct?

So, I will have to go for Code Grant authentication but it will require Client Secret. Problem with that is, when a User 'add' my App to his/her BIM360 account, it won't be able to generate and pass Client Secret to my app. Correct?

Comment: Part 2:
It also means that I can't satisfy BIM360 store requirement that app should be usable right after User has added it from Store to his/her account. 

Is there a solution for this?

By the way, in your previous comment, you mentioned that Code Grant type doesn't receive a Refresh Token, but it is other way around, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing concepts here:

1. **BIM 360 Provisioning**: this is performed once by the BIM 360 Account Admin. Only the **Forge Client ID** is required for this step. As [described here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-docs-provisioning-forge-apps), the account admin will specify that the app can access the account information and files via a 3-legged token.
2. **OAuth 3-legged**: each user that sign into your app will need to perform this authorization. As mentioned, this can be [Code Grant](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/) or [Implicit Grant](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token-implicit/), please read about the differences on the respective links. In summary, the first is performed on your app server-side with ID & Secret, the second is performed on your app client-side with Client ID (which is inevitably exposed). As your user stays for a long time on your app, I would suggest a **Code Grant** time and your app makes sure to refresh the token when it expires.

As you mentioned *webapp* the answer is for server and client. What's the programming language you have?

**EDIT**

[C# web sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-sample)

Comment: Ok, so, how it is going to work is:

1. Admin provisions the app, which includes manual copy & pasting of Client ID and Client Secret into my app's configuration page.

2. Then, other BIM360 users will start seeing the app, and it should be immediately available (which is not a problem if step-1 is performed).

Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Programming language on server side is C# and Python. Only HTML/CSS/JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: Correct, except that on (1) it's manual copy&paste of the Client ID (only). The Client Secret should NEVER be exposed